# Representing treelike/networklike guide in a database

Tags: database, oop, graph, nosql, relational-database

I am thinking about creating something like a tree- or networklike guide with Java objects with mapping it into a DB.
Following each step leads to another and so on, the following question/task/whatever depends on the former action. (see picture) It should be possible to create cycles for e. g. repeating some former steps.

What database should I prefer? Standard relational ones, connecting a table maybe with itself (foreign key -> primary key) to connect the nodes or some document-based (graph-based) like OrientDB, creating real trees? What about object-oriented databases like **db4o**?

What would have the better performance and/or be easier to realize?

Thanks in advance.

---

Additional thoughts:
I probably would add different actions (calls of webservices, whatsoever) and/or media (text, images, videos) to one node (step), leading to other steps, maybe getting back to a former one and so on.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track with graph databases. OrientDB looks like it would work really well. Also of course I'll throw out Neo4j, which should work just as good.

A relational database in my opinion is easy to toss out because it doesn't map well to the problem space. You might be able to create good structures to store relationships etc., but the queries will be horrific and complex.

The most important question I would ask is, "What does the query language look like?" Storing data usually isn't that hard to do. You can design structures and load data just fine.

When you need to query and think about your data though ... is the query language easy to reason about? Does it represent the concepts that are important to you?

For graphs, I really like Gremlin.  https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Gremlin-Query-Language

It has a pretty natural syntax for conveying graph concepts. I'd check that out as an alternative to OrientDB.

Comment: Yes, I looked at Neo4j already, too. Seems to be quite similar to OrientDB. Mainly it should easily be usable in Java. Both should do that. (Am open for other recommondations though)

Comment: After some research: What about e. g. db4o? What disadvantages does a objectDB have in comparison to document/graph-based DBs?

Comment: I haven't worked with object oriented databases, so I wouldn't know. =(